# Why is there a nested item instantiated with a new invoice in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails application I have `invoices` which can have many `items`:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :number, :items_attributes # some omitted for brevity

  has_many :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :reject_if => :all_blank

  def build_item(user)
    items.build(
      :price    => default_item_price(user), 
      :tax_rate => user.tax_rate
    )
  end

  private

    def real_hourly_rate
      project.real_hourly_rate if project.present?
    end

    def default_item_price(user)
      real_hourly_rate || user.hourly_rate
    end

end
```

---

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(:number => current_user.next_invoice_number)
    #@invoice.build_item(current_user)
  end 

end
```

Just underneath my form in `views/invoices/new.html.erb` I put this line to check how many `items` get instantiated with a new `invoice`:

```
<p>No. of items: <%= @invoice.items.length %></p>
```

My problem is that I get **1** where I expect to see **0** (note that I commented out the second line in my `new` controller action above).

Can anybody explain to me why this is?

It is causing me all sorts of trouble.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show the constructor, if you have one, for your `Invoice` model?

Comment: @mbratch: If by *constructor* you mean an `initialize` method, then I'm afraid I am not using one here.

Comment: @Neeraj: I get this then: `No. of items: [#<Item id: nil, invoice_id: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, price: 7000, quantity: #<BigDecimal:7fb0d9120818,'0.1E1',9(36)>, tax_rate: #<BigDecimal:7fb0de209b30,'0.1E2',9(36)>, position: 1381145143591, date: nil>]`

Comment: OK that's good to know. Do you have an `initialize` in your `User` model? It does seem there's some code you have that's missing which is causing the associated item to appear. Based only upon what little code you're showing, it shouldn't be creating an item, I don't think.

Comment: No, I don't have that in my `User` model either. I posted some more details above, though.

Comment: It appears that your `build_item` is being called when you do the `build` for an Invoice, thus creating the `item` in your invoice.

Comment: You mean calling `current_user.invoices.build` automatically builds an `item` as well? Let me investigate that...

Comment: @item = Item.new(params[:item]) then item.save should be present somewhere. Item is not being created. Inspect params too.

Comment: Ah yes, got it. I just realised that I am using `build_item(user)` inside my `InvoicesHelper` as well. It's a little `Add` button that initializes another `item` (just in case a user clicks on it). That's why I always had one `item` too much. Thank you very much for your help. I wouldn't have found it without you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I always had one `item` too much was that I was using the `build_item(user)` method in my `InvoicesHelper` as well. I removed that function and now I get the number of items that I expect.